# storage allocated on class definiton

Tags: c++

Given the following definition:

```
 class C{};
```

How much space gets allocated?  What are the methods  created at this stage?  Now I thought space is not allocated until instantiation but I guess this is only partly true. 
Edit:
I checked in my compiler sizeof(C) but it is 1 byte though i am not creating any object of the class.

Try this link
http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=319

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, the size is `1`, but only when you create instances of the class. A size of an object cannot be `0`.  If you do not create an instance, the only space added should be that used by the default member functions, which should be optimized out.

A compiler-generated default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, destructor, assignment operator, and move assignment operator get generated, albeit they do nothing.

Comment: And if empty class is inherited then it will most likely have no impact on the derived class size.

Comment: Default member functions are only synthesized if need arises for them to be synthesized not always.If there is no class instance then a default constructor will never be generated/defined,there is no overhead.

Comment: @alexm you are right,i checked that but what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Only thing guaranteed by the C++ Standard is that the size will be non-zero.

It is implementation defined as to what the exact size will be.Most of the implementations will have a size of `1` for a empty class.

Note that the default member functions will be synthesized only if there is some code which needs those functions. Also, these functions do not add to the size of the class instance. They are not allocated for each object.

Good Read, in Bjarne's own words:
[Why is the size of an empty class not zero?](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#sizeof-empty)

Answer (score 0):

(The following answer has been verified on GCC 4.4.)

The mere definition of a simple, nonpolymorphic type like your `C` neither makes the executable larger nor takes any space on the stack (or on the heap, or anywhere else).  It will enlarge the compiler's symbol table temporarily at compile time, and it may emit a debugging symbol if you have asked the compiler to do this, but I don't think that this was the thrust of your question.  Otherwise, your `C` takes no space until an actual object of type `C` is instantiated, as in

```
C your_c;
C my_c;
```

So as to be uniquely addressable, each object of type `C` then occupies one, unused byte.

Now, to be complete:  there is a hidden, intermediate issue.  Your toolchain may or may not emit a symbol for the unused type as part of the prelinked object file -- the file whose name ends in ".o" or ".obj".  My compiler doesn't (I just tried it), but yours might.

If all of that seems too technical, then a fair approximation to or summary of the answer is this:  your code takes no space.